# Anonymous referral links

Tags: feature-request

It seems that referral links currently tell visitors which user referred them. For privacy reasons I would prefer to be able to refer users from outside networks without revealing to the world which SE account is mine.

I could forgo the use of referral links altogether, but I would like to participate in the referral program. Is this currently possible or can it be?

Edit: It works both ways. I just found a SE user's connect.microsoft.com profile using the google search term `"http://stackoverflow.com/q/" "/000000"` (user ID has been replaced with zeros).

As it stands, users should be aware and responsible for their privacy I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The URL contains your user ID:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289840/1783619
```

The "1783619" is my id. You can safely remove it and the link will still work. Of course, because that is how the system tracks that it was *your* link that was clicked, you won't get any "credit" for it.

To "opt-out" just share the simpler link:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289840
```

Comment: So there is currently no way to participate in the referral system anonymously, as far as the public is concerned? I still want SE to be able to track my referrals.

Comment: @iyrin That is correct. The extra piece of the URL is the only way SE knows it was you who shared the link. Honestly, I can't think of any *other* way to do it off the top of my head.

Comment: How about a GUID? Or any other unique ID that does not match a user ID?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That could work, though would entail generating and storing it *every* time the "share" link was clicked. If I had to guess, that would be undesirable to the point of not doing that implementation. If thats the approach the OP decides to go for, the question should be updated to include it.

Comment: Not necessarily, each user could be assigned one UID, which does not match their user ID, possibly with an option to change it should someone ever figure out which UID belongs to who.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Sure, that would work even better.

Comment: @iyrin I would think you would just have a "share ID" private field in your profile with an option to generate a new one. That would replace the UserID in all future shares, no real reason to keep the old one as far as I'm concerned. If people wanted it there could be a check box indicating which to use.

Comment: I suppose it comes down to this being a concern for enough users to be worth the trouble then. I would definitely prefer it for sharing referrals with a large audience.

Comment: I bet it becomes a greater concern for people if the proposed sexuality Q&A reaches 100% commitment

Comment: @iyrin lol, very true. Until then (and probably even then), I suspect it will remain low-priority. Given there is a way to anonymize it (granted, without the tracking) there are bigger things on SE's plate. You never know though!

Comment: @iyrin Wouldn't be the first time sexuality.SE hit 100% commitment. :) If it actually makes it out of private beta, *then* we can start worrying about privacy implications.